# call a method, when a trigger sets a property

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have this style:

```
private Style ColorStyle(Container.ColorTrigger trigger)
        {
            Style style = new Style();
            style.TargetType = typeof(DataGridRow);           
            DataTrigger dtGreen = new DataTrigger();
            bool triggervalue = Convert.ToBoolean(trigger.Trigger);

            IValueConverter converter = AssignConverter(trigger.Operator);         
            dtGreen.Binding = new Binding(trigger.Binding) { Converter = converter, ConverterParameter = trigger.Value };
            dtGreen.Value = !triggervalue;
            dtGreen.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.LawnGreen));
            DataTrigger dtRed = new DataTrigger();
            dtRed.Binding = new Binding(trigger.Binding) { Converter = converter, ConverterParameter = trigger.Value };
            dtRed.Value = triggervalue;
            dtRed.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
            style.Triggers.Add(dtGreen);
            style.Triggers.Add(dtRed);

            return style;
        }
```

The style is set on a `DataGrid`.

how do I call a method, when the trigger sets `Brushes.Red` as `BackgroundProperty` AND how do I get the row which background is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a handler on TargetUpdated in Binding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.targetupdated.aspx

Comment: Gets fired before the color is changed

Comment: It gets fired after the target has been updated notifing that the target was updated.

Comment: "how do I call a method, when the trigger sets Brushes.Red as BackgroundProperty" - This does not work for that, because it gets fired BEFORE the backgroundproperty has actually changed.
It does allow me to see when the collection is updated though.

Comment: If you take a look on msdn you will notice: Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) raises a data update event each time that the binding source or target has been updated. So what do you mean with BEFORE?

Comment: if i update the source so that the trigger fires, the event fires before the setter kicks in. meaning i get the datagrid before the row color has changed to the new color

Comment: from where, how and when do you call ColorStyle method?

Comment: That is maybe your mistake. The DataGrid shall be created in xaml with its tirggers and style. Only thing you need is ItemsSource of DataGrid to be bound to a property in ViewModel which you sooner or later fill with data from Database.

Comment: but there are several datagrids - and not same amount every time, depends on how many tables have been created through the interface. each datagrid depends on different data and different triggers which are setup from the interface.

Comment: So you have a ListBox with DataTemplate that holds DataGrid which ItemsSources binds to a table in Database?